# Specific heat capacity and the periodic table

Tags: homework, periodic-table

Can someone explain me how can I use the periodic table in order to find the specific heat capacities of some elements? (for example, of Aluminium )

The question I have encountered is as follows:

> Given the specific heat capacities of the following liquids, use the periodic table in order to find the specific heat capacities of the metals $Al, Fe, Cu, Au $ .
>
> $ H_2 O - 4.18 J  /g \cdot C $, $ C_2 H_5 OH - 2.46 $ , $CCl_4 - 0.861 $ , $CCl_2 F_2 - 0.598 $ .

Comment: Either some context is missing, or the question as pasted can be nominated for “worst homework of the year” awards…

Answer (score 2):

Either you have a periodic table that features the specific heat capacity of elements in their standard state at STP (standard temperature and pressure), in which case you merely have to look it up, or you don't, and there's nothing you can do.

Specific heat capacity of materials, even elemental solids, are physical properties resulting from complex behavior of the systems, and cannot be determined by simple laws or equations. They have to be determined experimentally, or by [first principles calculations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ab_initio_quantum_chemistry_methods).

---

PS: water, methanol, carbon tetrachloride and dichlorodifluoromethane have got nothing to do with it.

Comment: Well...I'll ask our lecturer about this... Thanks anyway !